# Extracting specific lines from log file with grep and awk

Tags: awk, grep, logs

I have a huge log file (20 millions of lines) telling me if some url status are responding "200 OK" or not.

I'd like to extract all url with status "200 OK", plus the filename attached with it.

Input example:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2019-02-06 07:38:43--  https://www.example/download/123456789
Reusing existing connection to website.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: application/zip
  Connection: keep-alive
  Status: 200 OK
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile123.zip"
  Last-Modified: 2019-02-06 01:38:44 +0100
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Cache-Control: private
  X-Runtime: 0.312890
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Access-Control-Request-Method: GET,OPTIONS
  X-Request-Id: 99920e01-d308-40ba-9461-74405e7df4b3
  Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 00:38:44 GMT 
  X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.1.11
  Server: nginx + Phusion Passenger 5.1.11
  X-Powered-By: cloud66
Length: unspecified [application/zip]
Last-modified header invalid -- time-stamp ignored.
Remote file exists.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2019-02-06 07:38:43--  https://www.example/download/234567890
Reusing existing connection to website.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Connection: keep-alive
  Status: 404 Not Found
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  X-Runtime: 0.020718
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Access-Control-Request-Method: GET,OPTIONS
  X-Request-Id: bc20626b-095f-4b28-8322-ad3f294e4ee2
  Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 00:37:42 GMT
  X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.1.11
  Server: nginx + Phusion Passenger 5.1.11
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

Desired Output:

```
https://www.example/download/123456789 myfile123.zip
```

I'd love to finally understand the logic behind.

If I do this:

```
awk '/: 200 OK/{print $0}' file.log
```

I get all lines with `Status: 200 OK` but without the context.

If I do this:

```
grep -C4 "1 200 OK" file.log
```

I get the context but with "noise". I'd like to rearrange the output to get only the relevant information on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `awk` as below. Store the URL first in a variable and then on the `Status` line if its `OK` get the filename from the subsequent line. It should work on GNU `awk` as the `match()` function would need the third argument to store the captured group in an array.

```
awk '/^--/{ url = $NF } 
    /^[[:space:]]+Status/ && $NF == "OK" { getline nextline; match(nextline, /filename="(.+)"/,arr); print url, arr[1] }' file
```

Comment: Truly amazing. I stared for 20 minutes in awe. I think I got the logic. This is pure power. Thanks a million for writing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=`awk '/Status: 200 OK/{x=NR+1}(NR<x){getline;print $NF}' filename | awk -F "=" '{print $NF}'| sed 's/"//g'`

awk '{a[++i]=$0}/Status: 200 OK/{for(x=NR-7;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' filename | awk -v i="$i" '/https:/{$1=$2="";print $0 " " i}'
```

output

```
https://www.example/download/123456789 myfile123.zip
```